# Tiller ploughing land. The tiller should leave marks on the sand materiel and while ploughing sand particles should emit from the tines of the tiller

Tags: cycles-render-engine, node-editor

I was able to create sand, however am unable to draw lines on it.I want to animate a tiller working on sand leaving lines on sand. Plse help with video

Comment: Seems like you need do do a search for ["dynamic paint"](https://www.google.com/search?q=blender+dynamic+paint&oq=blender+dynami&aqs=chrome.0.0j69i60j69i65j69i60j69i57j0.7592j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8)

Answer (score -1):

Use [Dynamic Paint](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/physics/dynamic_paint/introduction.html) to produce a Displacement.

[image]